# mutt: automatically show new mesages

Tags: email, mutt, inotify

When I have mutt opened, I don't see new emails until I press a key, for example arrow down. Then new emails appear. 
Is there a way for mutt do recognize that new email has arrived, and display the email automatically, without me having to press a key every few minutes?

I am using maildir format (locally stored emails). What would be the best way? Should mutt check every n seconds, or should it be notified by the OS, perhaps using inotify ?

Comment: Is `check_new` on? (It is by default.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe I found a solution to this on the [Mutt wiki](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Folder).

> How to make mutt check for new mail more often? What's the difference between $timeout
>       and $mail_check?
>
> After every keyboard input mutt updates the status of all folders. To receive "New mail
>       in ..." notifications even without needing to press a key, set $timeout == time to wait
>       for idle mutt (no key pressed) before the status is updated again as if a key were
>       pressed. To avoid too frequent folder access (bad connections via NFS or IMAP), set
>       $mail_check == minium time between 2 scans for new mail (external changes to folders)
>       in case of high keyboard activity.
>
> $mail_check < $timeout : scan on next update $timeout < $mail_check : update before scan
>
> This means $mail_check < $timeout is more useful, because by the time mutt will update,
>       it will also scan for external changes to incorporate them in the update.
>
> How to get informed about new mail?
>
> When new mail arrives, an automatic (no key pressed) "New mail in ..." notification is
>       shown at the screen bottom. This happens only in the index menu. For manual checking,
>       you can use the buffy-list function which works in the pager, index and folder browser.
>       It prints a list of folders with new mail. However, it will display an up-to-date list
>       only when the index menu is focused. Additionally, you can invoke check-new in the
>       folder browser which updates the display ('N' flag for folders with new mail) and also
>       buffy-lists folder list.

I find this confusing and badly explained, but I tried it by adding `set timeout=30` to my `~/.muttrc` and it seems to work! The inbox view updates not long after my IMAP daemon reports having downloaded new mail. I hope this works for you too!

Comment: `set timeout=30` works great